# How to use ctags for code documentation

Tags: documentation, ctags

I have some source code that I want to document without touching the code. For every source file (e.g., `example.cpp`, `example.f90`, etc.) I would like to have a separate documentation file (e.g., `example.cpp.doc`, `example.f90.doc`) that has some metadata (ctag) linking it to the original source file.

Ideally I could open the source file and the documentation file in parallel views in my favorite editor (ViM) and have the two files synced so that they scroll together. In this manner, I can keep my documentation visually inline with the un-touched source code.

I know this is likely to be a unique scenario. But I'm hoping someone else has already figured this out.

**Is this even a possibility?**

Comment: "I can keep"...? You should finish this sentence.

Comment: @Vitor I've updated my question to finish the sentence. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I suggest using [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) to generate documentation for your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Create the initial .doc structure outside of Vim such that the "metadata" you want to keep is in the same line number as the original file.

Then open the two files in different Vim windows with `vim -O example.cpp example.cpp.doc`. At this point use `:windo set scrollbind` to enable scroll binding, which will allow to navigate any of the windows while keeping both in sync.

Comment: I have the tagbar plugin; it does a nice job of showing the tags that are in the current file. But it doesn't allow me to make any annotations associated with the tags, that's what I really want to do.

Comment: What about scrollbind?

Comment: scrollbind is what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to "bind" the source code file with the documentation file.

Comment: Tried to improve the answer to focus on the solution you need. Also included two commands that should be enough to get you started. The exercise of creating the initial .doc I will leave for you :)